# Laravel 5.7 Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to implement the reset password function using the built-in function from Laravel 5.7 as i have defined my routes in my `web.php`. I tried running `php artisan route:list` , It gave me an exception

**UPDATE**

Sorry for the lack of information given. I have already ran the command `php artisan make:auth` previously and the `Auth::routes()` has already been defined in `web.php` I am trying to access function `resets` in `ResetPasswords` traits through my `ResetPasswordController`but it gave an exception

> Class App\Http\Controllers\ResetPasswordController does not exist

I am using the pre-defined controller that is located at App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswor.php

**ResetPasswordController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{

    use ResetsPasswords;


    public function reset(Request $request){
        $reset = $this->reset($request);
    }

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->middleware('guest');
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Auth::routes();


Route::post('password/reset','ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Comment: error say dont find `SendsPasswordResetEmails` in your Auth folder check this

Comment: check the namespace of your missing class is correct too

Comment: Have you ran `php artisan make:auth` to let Laravel generate these classes? According to [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passwords#resetting-routing)
Also make sure you are calling the right classes, unless you have made some custom ones, they should be `Auth\ForgotPasswordController` and `Auth\ResetPasswordController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I have figured out where did i do wrong i had to add a `Auth\` in my routes

```
Route::post('password/reset','Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```